# Looping through products and getting individual savings

Tags: jquery, html, calculation

I am trying to loop through a series of products and get the individual savings for each product and display that as a message under each.

I have the following mechanism but it seems to calculate the first product then apply that calculation to all the products below?

HTML

```js
var num1 = parseInt($('.price > div').text().match(/\d+/)[0], 10);
var num2 = parseInt($('.worth-price').text().match(/\d+/)[0], 10);   
var diff = num2 - num1;

var savings = document.querySelectorAll('.productCard_price'), i;
for (i = 0; i < savings.length; ++i) {
  savings[i].innerHTML += "SAVE = " + diff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="productCard_price py-1">
   <div class="price">
      <div>£420.00
         <span class="text-gray productCard_package worth-price">
         WORTH £680.00
         </span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="productCard_price py-1">
   <div class="price">
      <div>£420.00
         <span class="text-gray productCard_package worth-price">
         WORTH £780.00
         </span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="productCard_price py-1">
   <div class="price">
      <div>£420.00
         <span class="text-gray productCard_package worth-price">
         WORTH £880.00
         </span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `diff`,`num1`,`num2` is only running once for the first element.

Try something like this to make it run for all the elements.

```
$('.productCard_price').each(function() {
  var num1 = parseInt($(this).find('.price > div').text().match(/\d+/)[0], 10);
  var num2 = parseInt($(this).find('.worth-price').text().match(/\d+/)[0], 10);
  var diff = num2 - num1;

  $(this).find(".price").append("<div>SAVE = " + diff + "</div>")
});
```

**Working demo**

```js
$('.productCard_price').each(function() {
  var num1 = parseInt($(this).find('.price > div').text().match(/\d+/)[0], 10);
  var num2 = parseInt($(this).find('.worth-price').text().match(/\d+/)[0], 10);
  var diff = num2 - num1;

  $(this).find(".price").append("<div>SAVE = " + diff + "</div>")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="productCard_price py-1">
  <div class="price">
    <div>£420.00
      <span class="text-gray productCard_package worth-price">
         WORTH £680.00
         </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="productCard_price py-1">
  <div class="price">
    <div>£420.00
      <span class="text-gray productCard_package worth-price">
         WORTH £780.00
         </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="productCard_price py-1">
  <div class="price">
    <div>£420.00
      <span class="text-gray productCard_package worth-price">
         WORTH £880.00
         </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks for this, glad I wasn't a million miles away but clarification of errors is always good to know.

Answer (score 0):

The problem happens because you get `num1` and `num2` outside of the loop. So, by default, jQuery with `$('price>div')` will only get the first element it finds, not all of them.

So you should declare your variables or at least give values to them, inside the `for` loop.

P.S. your code is a weird mix between vanilla javaScript and jQuery. I suggest that you only use vanilla javaScript .That's if  you don't **really** need jQuery. Yes, the below code would be longer and seem more complicated but it's worth it in terms of performance

```js
let savings = document.querySelectorAll('.productCard_price'), i;
for (i = 0; i < savings.length; ++i) {
const num1 = parseInt($(savings[i]).find('.price>div').text().match(/\d+/)[0], 10);
const num2 = parseInt($(savings[i]).find('.worth-price').text().match(/\d+/)[0], 10);   
const diff = num2 - num1;
  savings[i].innerHTML += `SAVE = ${diff}`;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="productCard_price py-1">
   <div class="price">
      <div>£420.00
         <span class="text-gray productCard_package worth-price">
         WORTH £680.00
         </span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="productCard_price py-1">
   <div class="price">
      <div>£420.00
         <span class="text-gray productCard_package worth-price">
         WORTH £780.00
         </span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="productCard_price py-1">
   <div class="price">
      <div>£420.00
         <span class="text-gray productCard_package worth-price">
         WORTH £880.00
         </span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please note that the use of ` dont work in IE, as in `SAVE = ${diff};

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen true, though i am using Babel so that's why i am used to write with ES6 syntax :)

Comment: @MihaiT That phrase about not really needing jQuery is kind of shooting yourself in the foot. Technically, you never really need jQuery, given it is only a framework built upon vanilla JS afterall. I see what you're getting at though. +1'd nonetheless *(anytime an answer gets rid off unnecessary jQuery)*